# Javascript sum fields in many select and put this value in a input

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm using this script for recovering some data from my database MYSQL and it works pretty fine. My page is in PHP.

```
 <script type = "text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("select#product1").on("change", function() {
        var id = this.value;
        $.ajax({
            url: "ajax.php",
            method: "post",
            data: "id=" + id,
            success: function(response) {
                var datashow = JSON.parse(response);
                price1 = datashow[0].price;
                time1 = datashow[0].time;
                $("input#totalprice").val(price1);
                $("input#totaltime").val(time1);
            }
        });
    });
}); </script>
```

My HTML is like this:

```
<select id="product1" name="product1">
    <option value="" selected="selected">-</option>
    <option value='17'>Product1</option>
</select>
<select id="product1" name="product2">
    <option value="" selected="selected">-</option>
    <option value='17'>Product1</option>
</select>
<select id="product1" name="product3">
    <option value="" selected="selected">-</option>
    <option value='17'>Product1</option>
</select>
<select id="product1" name="product4">
    <option value="" selected="selected">-</option>
    <option value='17'>Product1</option>
</select>
<select id="product1" name="product5">
    <option value="" selected="selected">-</option>
    <option value='17'>Product1</option>
</select>


<input id="totalprice" type="text" name="totalprice" />
<input id="totaltime" type="text" name="totaltime" />
```

In this way I'm able to fill my 2 different input: **totaltime** and **totalprice**, with the value recovered with my ajax.php file.

The problem is that I have 5 different select, not only product1 but also product2, product3, product4 and product5.

I need my 2 input, totalprice and totaltime, to be automatically filled in with the sum of the values recovered from my ajax, for each select.
It means I will have (or maybe not, they are not mandatory fields) price2 and time2, price3 and time3...

To be more clear: I have 5 different select fields, with dynamic products. Each of those products have a price and a time stored in mysql, that i recover through the json. I need to store the totalprice (sum of each of those) and the totaltime into an input.

Any idea to how I can solve this?

Thank you :)

Comment: Pretty unclear what are you trying to do. What is the problem you're facing exactly?

Comment: If I am understanding you correctly you want to loop through the json data and add each price to a total variable and then store it in the totalprice input?

Comment: exactly Larry Lane! :) I have 5 different select fields, with dynamic products. Each of those products has a price and a time stored in mysql, that i recover through the json. I need to store the totalprice (sum of each of those) and the totaltime into an input.

Comment: @AmedeoRicci, So you have five different input boxes with different costs in each one that is returned from your database?

Comment: that's it. In the example of my code I just recover the #product1 data. I need to recover the others too in the same way, but when I try it overwrites the totalprice it doesn't sum it.

Comment: @AmedeoRicci Does my answer make any sense to you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am understanding you correctly you want to loop through the json data and add each price to a total variable and then store it in the totalprice input. I am assuming the html markup and you will have to adjust your id and class names to match. Now of course the values of each input will be added dynamically from your database during your AJAX call and it looks like you have already figured that part out. Just make sure you put the JavaScript code inside of your Ajax success function.

[Live Preview](http://codepen.io/larryjoelane/pen/mPVyON)

**HTML:**

```
<select class="product" name="product1">
<option value="" selected="selected">-</option>
<option value='20'>20</option>
</select>
<select class="product" name="product2">
    <option value="" selected="selected">-</option>
    <option value='30'>30</option>
</select>
<select class="product" name="product3">
    <option value="" selected="selected">-</option>
    <option value='40'>40</option>
</select>
<select class="product" name="product4">
    <option value="" selected="selected">-</option>
    <option value='15'>15</option>
</select>
<select class="product" name="product5">
    <option value="" selected="selected">-</option>
    <option value='22'>22</option>
</select>    

<input id="totalprice" type="text" name="totalprice" />
<input id="totaltime" type="text" name="totaltime" />
```

**JavaScript/JQuery(Placed at the end of your Ajax Success Function):**

```
var total = 0;

//I am using this to simulate your ajax function since I don't have access to your database
$("select").on("change", function() {

  //Place the following code at the bottom of your ajax success function

  //clear out the total to
  //prevent old prices from being added to the total
  total = 0;

  $(".product").each(function() {

    //if the value is not an empty string
    if ($(this).val() !== "") {

      //add the price to the total
      total += parseInt($(this).val());

    }

  }); //end each function

  //update the total
  $("#totalprice").val(total);

}); //end on change event
```

**Update Optional Solution:** Based on your comments I belive you will want to do something like following. Now keep in mind you will have to change the url of your ajax call and switch the value of datashow variable back to what you had it. I had to change it to use a json file to simulate your call to the database.

**HTML:**

```
    <div id="products">
<select id="product1" name="product1">
    <option value="" selected="selected">-</option>
    <option value='17'>Product1</option>
</select>
<select id="product2" name="product2">
    <option value="" selected="selected">-</option>
    <option value='17'>Product1</option>
</select>
<select id="product3" name="product3">
    <option value="" selected="selected">-</option>
    <option value='17'>Product1</option>
</select>
<select id="product4" name="product4">
    <option value="" selected="selected">-</option>
    <option value='17'>Product1</option>
</select>
<select id="product5" name="product5">
    <option value="" selected="selected">-</option>
    <option value='17'>Product1</option>
</select>
        </div>

<input id="totalprice" type="text" name="totalprice" />
<input id="totaltime" type="text" name="totaltime" />
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#products select").on("change", function() {
        var id = this.value;
        $.ajax({
            url: "ajax.json",
            method: "get",
            data: "id=" + id,
            success: function(response) {               

         //initialize totalPrice to 0 if doesn't contain a value
         var totalPrice = $("#totalprice").val() !== "" ? parseInt($("#totalprice").val()): 0;

                var datashow =  response;//JSON.parse(response);
                var price1 = parseInt(datashow[0].price);
                var time1 = datashow[0].time;


                //add the total price
                $("input#totalprice").val(totalPrice + price1);

                //Do something similar for time, I don't how you plan on parsing this?
                $("input#totaltime").val(time1);


            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I wasn't able to make it work. I published my html so it can maybe help

Comment: @AmedeoRicci, You can't have duplicate id values in your html. To begin you will have to change that. I would switch to a class name instead.

Comment: @AmedeoRicci, Check out my live example now, I believe this something like what you are trying to achieve. I can't access your database with an ajax call obviously so I used an on change event to simulate updating the product selected. I will updated the code in my answer in just a minute.

Comment: your example looks perfect, I'm having troubles in making the sum of data using my json. Probably because in your example you use the value, which is not my case. I have to sum a special field recovered from the json. I'll make some test then let you know! thank you in the meanwhile :)

Comment: @AmedeoRicci I see I will fork my example and provide an alternate solution that should get you closer to what you need.

Comment: @AmedeoRicci Ok I posted an update to my solution that should do something close to what you want. I didn't know how to wanted to parse the time but once you figure out the price total using my solution you will be able implement that the way you want. You will also want to additional validation inside your on change event if you don't want it to total something if someone selects the - from your dropdown but once you figure out the basic functionality you need from my example you can always ask another question if you can't figure it out.

Comment: @AmedeoRicci No problem I am glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

When you add value into text box before that check the value of this box

```
var value1 =$("input#totalprice").val();
var totalPrice = parseInt(price1)+parseInt(value1 );
$("input#totalprice").val(totalPrice);
```

Comment: I think there is a mistake, your var totalPrice is not used. Anyway if I use it in the last raw it still doesn't seem to work. I published my HTML so it can maybe help

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
  var price = parseInt($("input#totalprice").val());
  var time= parseInt($("input#totaltime").val());

  $("input#totalprice").val(price+price1);
  $("input#totaltime").val(time+time1);
```

Comment: it joins the different values, it doesn't make the sum. For example if I have the first value that is 5 and the second that is 10, it shows 510 not 15. More than this, in the first selection it shows NaN because the totalprice was in the beginning empty.